# Entity Framework 6 passing 0 to nullable int

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, shadowing

Entity Framework 6 is passing `0` instead of `null` when using `AddOrUpdate()` in update scenario. The code runs fine in insert scenario.

Following is the code:

```
public class RecordDetail
{
     public int CreationUserId { get; set; }
     public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
     public int? ModifiedUserId { get; set; }
     public DateTime? ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey(nameof(CreationUserId))]
     public User CreationUser { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey(nameof(ModifiedUserId))]
     public User ModifiedUser { get; set; }
}

public class Role :RecordDetail
{
     [Key]
     public int RoleId { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [StringLength(100)]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
     public new int? CreationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

```
Role superAdmin = new Role
{
     Name = "Super Admin",
     IsDeleted = false,
     CreationUserId = null,
     CreationDateTime = currentDateTime
};
context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, superAdmin);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Following error occured:

```
SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_USecurity.Role_USecurity.User_CreationUserId". The conflict occurred in database "DB", table "USecurity.User", column 'UserId'.
```

SQL Produced by EF

```
UPDATE [USecurity].[Role]
SET [CreationUserId] = @0, [CreationDateTime] = @1
WHERE ([RoleId] = @2)
-- @0: '0' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: '9/13/2020 10:40:02 PM' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @2: '1' (Type = Int32)
```

Comment: Your RecordDetail base class has a non-nullable CreationUserId, while your sub-class has an overloaded null-able CreationUserId which should be giving you a compiler warning as you're not using the `new` overload keyword. I'm thinking if these details are optional then RecordDetail.CreationUserId should be null-able and remove the extra column from Role.

Comment: @StevePy I have already placed the new keyword to hide the base class CreationUserId